# Have Maven change JAR output directory based on property

Tags: java, apache, maven

I need Maven to package and output my project to a certain directory based on which profile is passed in at command line. I can't seem to find how to do it.

EDIT: Or if one is selected, output to one directory. If one isn't being used, output to default.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override maven project property in your profile for your need

```
<!-- in your profile -->
.
.
.
<build>
<project.build.directory>foo</project.build.directory>
</build>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up adding a default profile, else it would crash on me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>diffoutputdir</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${myoutputdir}</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```